# Using bash grep -Po regex fails if string has an underscore

Tags: regex, bash, grep, localization, collation

I have searched and even *gasp* read man pages and I still can't figure out whats up with this and how to fix it... I admit to being a regex newb, so no shame! (Ubuntu 12.04, bash 4.2.25, GNU grep 2.10)

As part of a script that does a bunch of other interesting things (which all seem to work) I'm attempting to extract data from file names... there are certain expected patterns that exist.. for example some file names will have a date: the date is in the format "YYYY-MM-DD" handily I can grep out the whole thing and break it down later by grepping with `'\b[0-9]{4}.{1}[0-9]{2}.{1}[0-9]{2}\b'` (in fact I can usually safely target the year directly with `'\b[0-9]{4}\b'` ) this works fine if the input string looks like either of these:

```
something 1989-07-23 something.jpg" or "foo-2013-01-10-bar.csv
```

but if it looks like `wordsidon'tcareabout_2004-09-14_otherthings.tif` or this `foofoobarbar_2010-07-16.gif` grep finds no matches.

What gives with the underscores? why do they cause my regex to fail? and is there a better way to go about this that I may be ignorant of? I have ultra-minimal perl and java skills, but I know my way around bash pretty well... or I thought I did...

I suppose I could rename the files, but that just seems inelegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp uses `\b`, which matches the boundary between word and non-word characters. The problem is that `_` is a word character, and so are digits, so there's no boundary between `_` and `2`.

You can use

```
[^0-9][0-9]{4}.{1}[0-9]{2}.{1}[0-9]{2}[^0-9]
```

instead. If the date can be at the beginning or end of the filename, use:

```
([^0-9]|^)[0-9]{4}.{1}[0-9]{2}.{1}[0-9]{2}([^0-9]|$)
```

Comment: aha! This means I can no longer target the year directly as '[0-9]{4}' would also find matches in 123456-1942-07-11-foobar.txt that I DON'T want, but I think I can work with omitting the boundaries. Thanks! (darn, sneaky word characters!)

Comment: You can replace `[^0-9]` with a character class listing the specific characters you want to allow as boundaries.